# Symfony2 get data of form

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning Symfony2 and I'm blocked at a point.

I did a form and I can get the values but I don't know how to get a field of an object

Code for creating the form :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => array('o' => 'Invoice','v' => 'Reconciliation')))    
        ->add('clients','entity',array(
        'class' => 'PVRecsBundle:Client',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.legalcompanyname','ASC');
        },
        'property' => 'legalCompanyName',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false))           
        ->add('dates','date',array('widget' => 'choice', 'input' => 'timestamp'))
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

And the code for getting the datas :

```
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $data = $form->get('clients')->getData();
        dump($data);

    }
```

I get the right datas but I get all the fields of my client.

the dump of my var :

```
Client {#654 ▼
       -id: 11334
       -name: 101579
       -identifiercdr: 101579
       -vatnumber: ""
       -einnumber: ""
        ....
       }
```

but now how do I get the field identifiercdr per example

The error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class PV\RecsBundle\Entity\Client could not be converted to string
```

I think it should be something like :

```
$data = $form->get('clients')['identifiercdr']->getData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$client = $form->get('clients')->getData();
$identifiercdr = $client->getIdentifiercdr();
```

(I am assuming that your `Client` entity has a getter for the `identifiercdr` field. If it does not, add it)